# Como verificar se uma sessão ($_SESSION) existe ou está ativa em PHP?

Tags: php, session

existe algum função nativa do `PHP` que possa utilizar para verificar se uma sessão de determinado usuário está aberta?

Por exemplo, tenho uma `$_SESSION['usuario'] = "400379d4eaa6ec24826dd44cd5cf65a3"` e quero consultar se ela está ativa no servidor `PHP` que está com a sessão ativa.

Isso, através de outra página, externa, por exemplo, se alguém chamar: `http://meuenderecom.com.br/getSession.php?idUsuario=400379d4eaa6ec24826dd44cd5cf65a3` quero que retorne 'S' se a sessão estiver ativa, ou 'N' se a sessão estiver fechada.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você quer saber se uma **outra** sessão, que não a do usuário em questão, existe, certo? Se sim:

O PHP guarda os dados das sessões em uma pasta temporária no servidor, que você pode descobrir qual é, ou até mesmo definir, usando [session_save_path()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-save-path.php).

Para cada sessão, o PHP cria um arquivo `sess_{SESSION_ID}` nessa pasta. Você pode pegar a lista de arquivos (sessões) usando:

```
<?php
print_r(scandir(session_save_path()));
?>
```

Se você quiser saber se uma sessão específica existe, caso você tenha o SESSION_ID, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
<?php
session_start();
// $SESSION_ID = id da sessão que você quer saber se existe
echo (file_exists(session_save_path().'/sess_'.$SESSION_ID) ? "Existe!" : "Não existe!");
?>
```

Como parece que você quer buscar pelo 'usuario', você teria que fazer o *parse* desses arquivos e verificar pela informação que você precisa lá. Caso não queira fazer o *parse*, você pode pegar o ID de todas as sessões, que está no nome do arquivo e fazer um loop inicializando via `session_start($SESSION_ID)` e buscando pelo dado que você precisa conferir, nesse caso o usuário.

Vale lembrar que de nenhuma maneira isso é uma recomendação. Ainda há uma opção, que seria manipular as sessões você mesmo, setando um novo [handler](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php). Dessa forma você poderia guardar os dados num banco ou de outra maneira que preferir, mas você precisa ter certeza que sabe o que está fazendo!

Por fim, parece que você só quer saber se um usuário está online. Existem outras técnicas muito mais seguras e eficientes para se fazer isso, mas fica para uma próxima pergunta (ou até mesmo já deve ter uma sobre isso).

Answer (score 4):

pra fazer isso basta usar o comando isset(), no seu caso ficaria assim, usando um if ternário:

```
$valor = isset($_SESSION['usuario']) ? 'S' : 'N';
```

Comment: Mas em que lugar vou informar o `id` da sessão que quero verificar?  Eu atribuí a $_SESSION['usuario'] o código "400379d4eaa6ec24826dd44cd5cf65a3".

Comment: sua pergunta não está muito clara, por favor, edite-a pra que eu possa ajudar melhor

Comment: O que não entendeu? Veja: tenho uma sessão, em que atribuí a ela vários identificadores criptografados, e quero através de um desses identificadores saber se a sessão está ativa ou não, pelo ID e não pela sessão em si!

Answer (score -1):

Com essa pergunta na verdade acaba expressando talvez outras dúvidas, ideal estudar um pouco.
Se quiser pegar o `id` de sessão pode usar o `session_id()` porém existem outras variáveis acerca disto, por exemplo:
- Pode-se ter havido o encerramento da sessão do `usuario(session['usuario']`, mas a `session_id()` ainda poderá ser a mesma se não foi feito um *regenerate*... recomendo que pesquise um pouco sobre como funcionam sessões para todos podermos ajudá-lo melhor.