# PHP - Verificar se a sessão (login) está ativa

Tags: php, session

Eu preciso enviar um e-mail de notificação de abandono do produto no carrinho para o cliente depois de X minutos que ele saiu do site sem comprar.

Alguém conhece alguma maneira simples e eficaz de verificar se a sessão de login do usuário ainda está ativa no site?

Exemplo: listar todas as sessões ativas do site, se a sessão Y não estiver ativa, envia-se o e-mail de abandono do produto X minutos depois do cliente sair do site.

Comment: No PHP você pode definir o tempo de expiração de sessão, além disso, também dá para verificar se ainda tem uma  `session_id()`. e se a sessão criada ainda está ativa: `if ($_SESSION['status_sessao'] == 1) {  // faz algo } else { //logoff }`. Consulte o [php.net para entender como funciona a sessão](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.session.php). [Comece por aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php).

Comment: Ivan, só que eu não vou ter acesso a sessão do usuário. Desse modo, isso que você disse não funcionaria da maneira que eu quero.

Comment: Não entendi, como assim você não vai ter acesso a sessão? É o sistema que controla a sessão. Desculpe, mas creio que você não leu a documentação do PHP. Há outras maneiras de fazer isso, utilizando javascript. Porém você precisa entender como funciona sessões. Senão, não vou poder te ajudar.

Comment: Isso tudo vai ser dinâmico. Minha ideia é fazer um script que verifica se a sessão do usuário que abandonou o produto no carrinho está ativa ou não. Se ela estiver ativa, envio um e-mail pra ele sobre o produto.

Comment: E qual é a dificuldade nisso? não entendi. "faz algo" seria o disparo. Sabe identificar quando alguém abandonou o carrinho, você não pode considerar a sessão do cara. Tem que considerar quando a compra não é  efetuada dentro de um determinado prazo. Não tem a ver com tempo de sessão.

Comment: Leia o comentário do Berriel nessa publicação: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115965/como-verificar-se-uma-sess%C3%A3o-session-existe-ou-est%C3%A1-ativa-em-php
Isso seria o que eu estava procurando.

Comment: Você pode comparar a data que o carrinho foi criado, e verificar se um pedido foi gerado na mesma data do carrinho. Se não foi, você enviar um email, usando crontab para lembrar o usuário que ele não deu "comprar". Agendando o disparo no final do dia, para ele receber logo de manhã a mensagem. Muito mais simples e eficaz.

Comment: Se o cara deslogar, e relogar, ele vai ficar recebendo mensagens...

Comment: To achando que o uso de sessões pra ficar verificando o que eu quero vai ficar muito complexo pra uma coisa, teoricamente, simples. Vou utilizar apenas os dados que eu já tenho, que são a data que o produto foi adicionado no carrinho. Se passar de X minutos que foi adicionado e a compra não foi finalizada, eu envio o e-mail. Pra fazer essas verificações vou usar um script com crontab a cada Y minutos, acho que fica melhor assim e menos complicado.

Answer (score 2):

Eu precisei fazer isso em um sistema que eu desenvolvi, no caso não era um carrinho de compra mas lógica é a mesma.

1. A primeira coisa que você vai ter que fazer é criar um forma de controle para saber quando o usuário não estiver mais ativo no site. No meu caso criei na minha tabela de Usuário o campo **ultimaRegistro**(TIMESTAMP).
2. Na tela do cliente utilizei o javascript para fazer um ajax pulling de 10 em 10 segundos, requisitando um arquivo no meu servidor que atualizava a data do **ultimaRegistro** na tabela de Usuário.
3. Criar na tabela de **Carrinho de Produtos** o campo **notificacaoEnviada**(boolean), para controlar se eu já enviou notificação para esse carrinho.
4. Criar um script que varre todos os carrinhos que o campo **notificacaoEnviada** é false e que o campo **ultimaRegistro** foi atualizado a mais de X minutos. Nesse momento o script envia o email e atualiza o campo **notificacaoEnviada** para true.
5. Adicionar o script para rodar automático de X em X minutos. No meu caso eu utilizo o **crontab** do linux (para saber mais sobre o crontab acesse [esse link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info). 
   No meu caso utilizei dessa forma para rodar de 10 em 10 minutos:

   */10 * * * * php -q PATH_DO_SCRIPT$

Comment: Vou fazer algo similar a isso, mas usando somente a data de quando o produto foi adicionado no carrinho! Valeu.